# Prevent pagebreak between two "tabular" tables

Tags: tables, supertabular

I have a file with two tables generated by `tabular` environment. But the first table is very short but the second one is very long (several pages). As a result, my typesetting automatically starts the second table from a new page. Is there a way to stop this?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{tabular}{l l}
...
...
... (many lines)
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: 1) May be you should consider using one table environment with two tabulars [and caption package to give two captions with '\captionof{table}{Table No 1}' (if needed)] -put your code from first `\begin{tabular}` to last `\end{tabular}` inside `\begin{table}\centering` and `\end{table}` commands to test it -

Comment: @koleygr Thank you. I wasn't clear in the post. The two tables have different formats. The first one is like {tabular}{l l}. But the second one is like {tabular}{@{} p{3cm} p{13cm}}. Can I make them into one table?

Comment: Yes... A table can contain more than one tabulars... See the possible duplicate answer on how to add skip to separate them. And more captions too as I found out there (If needed for you)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).